# Shiny server not working . Gives ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: amazon-ec2, shiny-server, shinyapps

I had issues installing shiny-server in ubuntu 20.04 running on an AWS EC2. Finally i figured out a way to install it from the source. Seems to have installed ok but when i go to `https://<xxx>.amazonaws.com:3838/<appname>`, it doesn't load up the page. Instead, it gives this error

```
This site can't be reached. 
<xxx>.amazonaws.com took too long to respond. 
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I gave `sudo shiny-server` and got this

```
[2021-02-02T17:30:37.418] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.16.0 (Node.js v12.20.1)
[2021-02-02T17:30:37.420] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2021-02-02T17:30:37.459] [WARN] shiny-server - Running as root unnecessarily is a security risk! You could be running more securely as non-root.
[2021-02-02T17:30:37.462] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on http://[::]:3838
```

So that seems to be working fine.

I checked the security groups on EC2 and made sure it allows all inbound connections to port 3838.

Comment: You are trying to connect with https but the server is listening with http

Comment: can you telnet <your-ip> 3838